# MySQL: Order only values greater than a specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `data`
(`id` int, `x` int, `y` int);

INSERT INTO `data`
(`id`, `x`, `y`)
VALUES
(1, 5, 7),
(2, 9, 3),
(3, 4, 6),
(4, 0, 0),
(5, 0, 0),
(6, -1, 2);
```

I need to select all the data from the table and order them ascending by the greatest value from the pair (x, y). but only the values where both x and y are greater than 0. Rows where one of the pair (x, y) is less than 0 should be placed below the ordered values and the rest of the rows at the end of the selected list.

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT `x`, `y`, GREATEST (`x`, `y`) as `result` FROM `data`
ORDER BY `result`=0, `result`=-1, `result` ASC
```

which gives me the following result:

```
X   Y   RESULT
-1  2   2
4   6   6
5   7   7
9   3   9
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

but my desired result is:

```
X   Y   RESULT
4   6   6
5   7   7
9   3   9
-1  2   2
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

SQLfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/995d2/6

Comment: btw .. I know the query is wrong because the condition `result`=-1 will be never true if I'm selecting `result` as the greatest value from (x,y). This query works if both values are "-1", but I need to modify it to work also if only one of the values is "-1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can do it using `case-when`

```
SELECT 
`x`, 
`y`, 
GREATEST (`x`, `y`) as `result` 
FROM `data` 
ORDER BY 
case 
  when x > 0 and y > 0 then 0 
  when x < 0  OR y < 0 then 1
  when result = 0 then 2
end,
result
ASC
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/995d2/58)**

Comment: But I need to order the `result` ascending and if I change DESC -> ASC, then it is again not correct.

Comment: thats in ascending order when both x and y is +ve then they will appear in ascending order followed by if one is -ve and then both 0 could you explain more on this ?

Comment: You can further simplify it by replacing `when result = 0 then 2` with a simple `else 2`:-)